# Bad state: no element error when no product is chosen

Tags: flutter, dart

```
get products => _products;
  get subtotal => _products.entries.map((product) => product.key.price*product.value ).toList();
  get total => products.entries.map((product) => product.key.price*product.value ).toList().
  reduce((value, element) => value + element);
```

This is my code, for calculating the total for the products chosen by the user.

```
class Product{
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;

  const Product({required this.name,required this.price,required this.imageUrl});
  static const List<Product> products = [
    Product(
      name: "Chicken ",
      price: 19.0,
      imageUrl:
      "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.hO1XEXeKmRBNgikv0JwJbgHaD4?pid=ImgDet&rs=1",
    ),
    Product(
      name:"Chicken Fillet" ,
      price: 17.0,
      imageUrl: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.9594f3119897ada014f2c058d97752a1?rik=USARWiyD6c6TXw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0",
    ),
    Product(
      name:"Shawarma Sandwitch" ,
      price: 7.0,
      imageUrl: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.5f2296c2f1908daf3ffc8c3b22466f4e?rik=vBiAwdGEc2VQ9g&pid=ImgRaw&r=0",
    ),
    Product(
      name:"Shrimp Fillet" ,
      price: 21.0,
      imageUrl: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.96ea64a0983eb63f7a2ef45a610d449b?rik=NoPXJ3oB0B9zFw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0",
    ),
    Product(
      name:"Shrimp Sandwitch" ,
      price: 8.0,
      imageUrl: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.hKSQvo-Jt_0m1ufTzh2rsgHaEV?pid=ImgDet&rs=1",
    ),
    Product(
      name:"Shrimp " ,
      price: 10.0,
      imageUrl: "https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.8267d39af16a5a20bda81eaba0aeb19b?rik=WFdmTaDL7%2bKfMw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0",
    ),
  ];
}
```

This is my list of products with their name, prices and images.

The problem is that when there are no products chosen by the user it gives an error of bad state: no element and i want it to give like a empty cart image. I tried many things but it cannot seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `_products.entries` you are using Map, you can check whether the map is empty or not and return based on it.

```dart
get subtotal => products.isEmpty ? [] : _products.entries.map((product) => product.key.price * product.value).toList();
get total => products.isEmpty ? 0 : products.entries.map((product) => product.key.price * product.value).toList().reduce((value, element) => value + element);
```

Comment: @Kabakebo please accept his answer